# How to set target settings for different builds

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova

In xcode 4.5 how do I select different target settings for different builds for example one target setting for debug, one target setting for release etc, so I can define different icons depending on the build etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options, neither perfect.  I'm going to focus on the concrete example of using different icons depending on your build configuration, as you suggest, though both techniques can be applied more broadly.

### Redirect in your Info.plist

This is the simplest way.  Specify your "Icon file" property in your target's Info.plist as e.g. "Icon-${CONFIGURATION}".  Then, create two ICNS icons, "Icon-Release.icns" and "Icon-Debug.icns", and add them to your project.  That's it.  The downside with this approach is that *both* icons will be copied into your built app every time, rather than just the one it needs.

### Use a "Run Script" build phase

This is a little more involved but it gives you a better result.  Add a Run Script build phase to your target, with the following script:

```
cp "$(dirname "${PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH}")/Icon-${CONFIGURATION}.icns" "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}"
```

Specify its output file as:

```
$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/$(UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH)/Icon.icns
```

And make sure your "Icon file" property in your Info.plist is set to just "Icon".

This relies on your icons sitting in the same folder as your Info.plist within your source tree (though you can edit the script however you like to suit your project's configuration).

Note also that with this approach Xcode won't be able to see that you have the icon set correctly, so for example in the "Summary" tab of your target's settings it'll still show the question mark placeholder for the icon.  You'll need to do an actual build to verify it's working.

Comment: Thanks for your help, although I did not see this message before I built my own solution ><. I managed to work out how to connect each target setting to a scheme and then link each scheme to a specific build configuration. So now I just select a scheme which will then use the right build configuration and target setting for the job. Then I just set each target setting to have different Icons. Not sure if thats the right thing to do but it works :p

Comment: That works, though the downside is you now have duplicate schemes that can get out of sync.  You can work around _that_ by putting all your settings into xcconfig files, but then you lose the GUI editor for them.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is pretty close from Wade's first point, you can also add an dynamic suffix using a user-defined settings in you project configuration.

[image: user-defined settings]

I use this solution to dynamize the icon, the bundle display name and also the bundle identifier of my build to be able to use the version from the app store beside my development version.

[image: info.plist dynamisation]